# Dividing a straight line into parts with certain constrains

Tags: geometry

I have to prove the following statement geometrically and I do not know what do to. Any help would be appreciated.

> "Divide a straight line into two parts so that the square on one part may be twice the square on the other"

I know the statement is pretty vague lol that's what it throwing me off.

Comment: Solving the quadratic equation $2x^2+x=L$? Use the quadratic formula :P

Comment: @KennyLau it has to be a geometric proof

Comment: You can use the quadratic formula with compass/straightedge construction.

Comment: We haven't learnt that in class so I doubt that's what I should do. Thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: It isn't a statement that you can prove. It's something that you construct. What tools do you have?

Comment: Say that the segment that you have to divide is $S$. Draw a square with side $S$. Then, extend the diagonal (which has length $\sqrt{2}S$) of the square with a segment of the same length as $S$. That gives us a segment of length $(1+\sqrt{2})S$. Join the end of that segment with the end of $S$ and draw a parallel to the line just drawn passing through the vertex of the square. This parallel line will divide the segment $S$ (the side of the square) in the proportion $\sqrt{2}/(1+\sqrt{2})$. Therefore, two segments of length ...

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}}S$ and $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}S$. Observe now, how their sum is $S$ and their squares are one the double of the other.